# Compare two StdClass objects with PHP

Tags: php, json, comparison, stdclass

I have two objects, which are the same, but written in different methods. One is JSON (decoded):

```
$object1 = json_decode('{"null":null,"int":1}');
```

And one is StdClass:

```
$object2 = (object)[
    "null" => null,
    "int"  => 1,
];
```

As you can see, they contain the exact same structure (both keys and values). nothing is different. So it should be equal. but... it's not.

```
echo json_encode($object1 === $object2);
// -> false
```

I thought maybe i'm wrong, and JSON is not an StdClass. so I used `var_dump` and still, they are the same:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["null"]=>
  NULL
  ["int"]=>
  int(1)
}

object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["null"]=>
  NULL
  ["int"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Now I'm frustrated and I don't know how to compare two objects, and detect changes between them.

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

I thought it might work if I'll change `$object1` from `JSON` to StdClass, like the second one:

```
$object1 = (object)[
    "null" => null,
    "int"  => 1,
];
```

But still... `false`.

Comment: read [object-comparison.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) - `==` vs. `===`

Comment: use `==` or do the opposite https://3v4l.org/d2XuL

Comment: Just stumbled on this and here's a better answer. (And you have a bug in your json code.) Basically `(object)[] === (object)[]` will be false because they are 2 different objects. While `(object)[] == (object)[]` is `true`, it's a bad comparison because it will *also* return `true` for `(object)[3] == (object)["3"]` (where one 3 is a string) due to it also doing loose comparison, so this is a bad solution. However `json_encode($object1) === json_encode($object2)` *will* actually give you the correct result as you want here. You can see this is NOT the same as the json example you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods for comparing objects. Using the `===` operator returns `true` if the objects you are comparing are the same instance of the same class. i.e. They are the same object.

Using the `==` operator returns true if all the properties of both objects are equal, and the objects are instances of the same class.

You're comparing two different objects, so `===` will returns false, but `==` should return true.

See https://3v4l.org/UdFFT

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must ask - How they are different? and what's the idea behind using `==` instead of `===`? I thought only when you're using `===` it means that you want the result to be "exactly equal"

Comment: Objects are always passed by reference. The expression `$obj2 = $obj1` passes a reference to `$obj1`, not the value. Using `==` and `===` this way allows the programmer to distinguish between two identical objects, and two references to the same object.

Comment: Regardless, this (OP's code) will never work `echo json_encode($object1 == $object2);`